# xorg.conf: Why does this have no effect?

Tags: resolution, xorg.conf, solaris-10

Here is my xorg.conf file. The problem is that my resolution setting 1600x900 is getting ignored. The resolution keeps popping to 1280x1024

**Edit** The resolution comes up as 640x480 after unplugging the physical monitor. When my file gets ignored, the system seems to read my monitor to find it's capabilities automatically. What I want is to access the system through a Lights Out Manager KVM device, so the physical monitor does not matter.

What is wrong with this file?

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "X.org Configured"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
EndSection

Section "Files"
    RgbPath      "/usr/X11/lib/X11/rgb"
    ModulePath   "/usr/X11/lib/modules"
    FontPath     "/usr/X11/lib/X11/fonts/TrueType/"
    FontPath     "/usr/X11/lib/X11/fonts/Type1/"
    FontPath     "/usr/X11/lib/X11/fonts/Type1/sun/"
    FontPath     "/usr/X11/lib/X11/fonts/F3bitmaps/"
    FontPath     "/usr/X11/lib/X11/fonts/misc/"
    FontPath     "/usr/X11/lib/X11/fonts/100dpi/"
    FontPath     "/usr/X11/lib/X11/fonts/75dpi/"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load  "IA"
    Load  "Xst"
    Load  "dbe"
    Load  "extmod"
    Load  "record"
    Load  "xtrap"
    Load  "glx"
    Load  "bitstream"
    Load  "type1"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Keyboard0"
    Driver      "keyboard"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Mouse0"
    Driver      "mouse"
    Option      "Protocol" "auto"
    Option      "Device" "/dev/mouse"
    Option      "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor0"
    Modeline "1600x900@75" 161.64 1600 1632 2240 2272 900 917 928 946
    Mode "1600x900@75"
        DotClock 161.64
        HTimings 1600 1632 2240 2272
        VTimings 900 917 928 946
        Flags "-HSync" "-VSync"
    EndMode
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Card0"
    Driver      "ast"
    VendorName  "Unknown Vendor"
    BoardName   "Unknown Board"
    BusID       "PCI:1:5:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Device     "Card0"
    Monitor    "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth     24
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
        Modes    "1600x900@75"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

**Edit:**  `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` after putting the config to what is shown above (there is a 3000 character limit so I will put dots in place of some of the log information that seems redundant)

```
X Window System Version 6.9.0 (Sun Xorg Release 1.1 for Solaris )
Release Date: 21 December 2005
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0, Release 6.9
Build Operating System: SunOS 5.10 Generic i86pc 
Current Operating System: SunOS typhoon1 5.10 Generic_118855-14 i86pc

SUNWxorg-server package version: 6.8.0.5.10.7400,REV=0.2004.12.15
SUNWxorg-server patches applied: 119062-01 118966-21
SUNWxorg-graphics-ddx package version: 6.8.0.5.10.7400,REV=0.2004.12.15
SUNWxorg-graphics-ddx patches applied: 118966-21
    Before reporting problems, check http://sunsolve.sun.com/
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
Module Loader present
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sun Nov  7 11:46:18 2010
(==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
(==) ServerLayout "X.org Configured"
(**) |-->Screen "Screen0" (0)
(**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor0"
(**) |   |-->Device "Card0"
(**) |-->Input Device "Mouse0"
(**) |-->Input Device "Keyboard0"
(==) Keyboard: CustomKeycode disabled
(**) FontPath set to "/usr/X11/lib/X11/fonts/TrueType/,/usr/X11/lib/X11/fonts/Type1/,/usr/X11/lib/X11/fonts/Type1/sun/,/usr/X11/lib/X11/fonts/F3bitmaps/,/usr/X11/lib/X11/fonts/misc/,/usr/X11/lib/X11/fonts/100dpi/,/usr/X11/lib/X11/fonts/75dpi/"
(**) RgbPath set to "/usr/X11/lib/X11/rgb"
(**) ModulePath set to "/usr/X11/lib/modules"
(II) Module ABI versions:
    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.2
    X.Org Video Driver: 0.8
    X.Org XInput driver : 0.5
    X.Org Server Extension : 0.2
    X.Org Font Renderer : 0.4
(II) Loader running on solaris
(II) LoadModule: "bitmap"
(II) Loading /usr/X11/lib/modules/fonts/libbitmap.so
(II) Module bitmap: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 6.8.0, module version = 1.0.0
    Module class: X.Org Font Renderer
    ABI class: X.Org Font Renderer, version 0.4
(II) Loading font Bitmap
(II) LoadModule: "pcidata"
(II) Loading /usr/X11/lib/modules/libpcidata.so
(II) Module pcidata: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 6.9.0, module version = 1.0.0
    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 0.8
(II) PCI: Probing config type using method 1
(II) PCI: Config type is 1
(II) PCI: stages = 0x03, oldVal1 = 0x80062068, mode1Res1 = 0x80000000
(II) PCI: PCI scan (all values are in hex)
(II) PCI: 00:00:0: chip 10de,0369 card 108e,534b rev a2 class 05,00,00 hdr 00
(II) PCI: 00:01:0: chip 10de,0364 card 108e,534b rev a3 class 06,01,00 hdr 80
(II) PCI: 00:01:1: chip 10de,0368 card 108e,534b rev a3 class 0c,05,00 hdr 80
(II) PCI: 00:02:0: chip 10de,036c card 108e,534b rev a1 class 0c,03,10 hdr 80
(II) PCI: 00:02:1: chip 10de,036d card 108e,534b rev a2 class 0c,03,20 hdr 80
(II) PCI: 00:04:0: chip 10de,036e card 108e,534b rev a1 class 01,01,8a hdr 00
(II) PCI: 00:05:0: chip 10de,037f card 108e,534b rev a3 class 01,01,85 hdr 80
(II) PCI: 00:06:0: chip 10de,0370 card 0000,0000 rev a2 class 06,04,01 hdr 81
(II) PCI: 00:08:0: chip 10de,0373 card 108e,534b rev a3 class 06,80,00 hdr 00
(II) PCI: 00:09:0: chip 10de,0373 card 108e,534b rev a3 class 06,80,00 hdr 00
(II) PCI: 00:0a:0: chip 10de,0376 card 0000,0000 rev a3 class 06,04,00 hdr 01
(II) PCI: 00:0b:0: chip 10de,0374 card 0000,0000 rev a3 class 06,04,00 hdr 01
(II) PCI: 00:0c:0: chip 10de,0374 card 0000,0000 rev a3 class 06,04,00 hdr 01
(II) PCI: 00:0d:0: chip 10de,0378 card 0000,0000 rev a3 class 06,04,00 hdr 01
(II) PCI: 00:0f:0: chip 10de,0377 card 0000,0000 rev a3 class 06,04,00 hdr 01
(II) PCI: 00:18:0: chip 1022,1100 card 0000,0000 rev 00 class 06,00,00 hdr 80
(II) PCI: 00:18:1: chip 1022,1101 card 0000,0000 rev 00 class 06,00,00 hdr 80
(II) PCI: 00:18:2: chip 1022,1102 card 0000,0000 rev 00 class 06,00,00 hdr 80
(II) PCI: 00:18:3: chip 1022,1103 card 0000,0000 rev 00 class 06,00,00 hdr 80
(II) PCI: 01:05:0: chip 1a03,2000 card 108e,534b rev 00 class 03,00,00 hdr 00
(II) PCI: 05:00:0: chip 1166,0103 card 0000,0000 rev b5 class 06,04,00 hdr 01
(II) PCI: 06:04:0: chip 14e4,1678 card 108e,534b rev a3 class 02,00,00 hdr 80
(II) PCI: 06:04:1: chip 14e4,1678 card 108e,534b rev a3 class 02,00,00 hdr 80
(II) PCI: End of PCI scan
(II) PCI-to-ISA bridge:
(II) Bus -1: bridge is at (0:1:0), (0,-1,-1), BCTRL: 0x0008 (VGA_EN is set)
(II) Subtractive PCI-to-PCI bridge:
(II) Bus 1: bridge is at (0:6:0), (0,1,1), BCTRL: 0x023b (VGA_EN is set)
(II) Bus 1 I/O range:
    [0] -1  0   0x0000e000 - 0x0000efff (0x1000) IX[B]
(II) Bus 1 non-prefetchable memory range:
    [0] -1  0   0xfd000000 - 0xfdefffff (0xf00000) MX[B]
(II) PCI-to-PCI bridge:
(II) Bus 2: bridge is at (0:10:0), (0,2,2), BCTRL: 0x0003 (VGA_EN is cleared)
(II) PCI-to-PCI bridge:
(II) Bus 3: bridge is at (0:11:0), (0,3,3), BCTRL: 0x0003 (VGA_EN is cleared)
(II) PCI-to-PCI bridge:
(II) Bus 4: bridge is at (0:12:0), (0,4,4), BCTRL: 0x0003 (VGA_EN is cleared)
(II) PCI-to-PCI bridge:
(II) Bus 5: bridge is at (0:13:0), (0,5,6), BCTRL: 0x0003 (VGA_EN is cleared)
(II) Bus 5 non-prefetchable memory range:
    [0] -1  0   0xfdf00000 - 0xfdffffff (0x100000) MX[B]
(II) PCI-to-PCI bridge:
(II) Bus 7: bridge is at (0:15:0), (0,7,7), BCTRL: 0x0003 (VGA_EN is cleared)
(II) Host-to-PCI bridge:
(II) Bus 0: bridge is at (0:24:0), (0,0,7), BCTRL: 0x0008 (VGA_EN is set)
(II) Bus 0 I/O range:
    [0] -1  0   0x00000000 - 0x0000ffff (0x10000) IX[B]
(II) Bus 0 non-prefetchable memory range:
    [0] -1  0   0x00000000 - 0xffffffff (0x0) MX[B]
(II) Bus 0 prefetchable memory range:
    [0] -1  0   0x00000000 - 0xffffffff (0x0) MX[B]
(II) PCI-to-PCI bridge:
(II) Bus 6: bridge is at (5:0:0), (5,6,6), BCTRL: 0x0027 (VGA_EN is cleared)
(II) Bus 6 non-prefetchable memory range:
    [0] -1  0   0xfdf00000 - 0xfdffffff (0x100000) MX[B]
(--) PCI:*(1:5:0) unknown vendor (0x1a03) unknown chipset (0x2000) rev 0, Mem @ 0xfd000000/23, 0xfdee0000/17, I/O @ 0xec00/7
(II) Addressable bus resource ranges are
    [0] -1  0   0x00000000 - 0xffffffff (0x0) MX[B]
    [1] -1  0   0x00000000 - 0x0000ffff (0x10000) IX[B]
(II) OS-reported resource ranges:
    [0] -1  0   0xffe00000 - 0xffffffff (0x200000) MX[B](B)
    [1] -1  0   0x00100000 - 0x3fffffff (0x3ff00000) MX[B]E(B)
    [2] -1  0   0x000f0000 - 0x000fffff (0x10000) MX[B]
    [3] -1  0   0x000c0000 - 0x000effff (0x30000) MX[B]
    [4] -1  0   0x00000000 - 0x0009ffff (0xa0000) MX[B]
    [5] -1  0   0x0000ffff - 0x0000ffff (0x1) IX[B]
    [6] -1  0   0x00000000 - 0x000000ff (0x100) IX[B]
(II) Active PCI resource ranges:
    [0] -1  0   0xfdfb0000 - 0xfdfbffff (0x10000) MX[B]E
    [1] -1  0   0xfdfc0000 - 0xfdffffff (0x40000) MX[B]E
    [2] -1  0   0xfdfe0000 - 0xfdffffff (0x20000) MX[B]E
    [3] -1  0   0xfdff0000 - 0xfdffffff (0x10000) MX[B]E
    [4] -1  0   0xfcff6c00 - 0xfcff6fff (0x400) MX[B]E
    [5] -1  0   0xfcffa000 - 0xfcffbfff (0x2000) MX[B]E
    [6] -1  0   0xfcff7000 - 0xfcff7fff (0x1000) MX[B]E
    [7] -1  0   0xfcffa400 - 0xfcffa7ff (0x400) MX[B]E
    [8] -1  0   0xfcffa800 - 0xfcffafff (0x800) MX[B]E
    [9] -1  0   0xfcff8000 - 0xfcffffff (0x8000) MX[B]E
    [10] -1 0   0xfcff9000 - 0xfcff9fff (0x1000) MX[B]E
    [11] -1 0   0xfcffac00 - 0xfcffafff (0x400) MX[B]E
    [12] -1 0   0xfcffb000 - 0xfcffbfff (0x1000) MX[B]E
    [13] -1 0   0xfdee0000 - 0xfdefffff (0x20000) MX[B](B)
    [14] -1 0   0xfd000000 - 0xfd7fffff (0x800000) MX[B](B)
    [15] -1 0   0x0000c800 - 0x0000c8ff (0x100) IX[B]E
    [16] -1 0   0x0000c880 - 0x0000c8ff (0x80) IX[B]E
    [17] -1 0   0x0000cc00 - 0x0000ccff (0x100) IX[B]E
    [18] -1 0   0x0000d000 - 0x0000d0ff (0x100) IX[B]E
    [19] -1 0   0x0000d080 - 0x0000d0ff (0x80) IX[B]E
    [20] -1 0   0x0000d400 - 0x0000d4ff (0x100) IX[B]E
    [21] -1 0   0x0000d480 - 0x0000d4ff (0x80) IX[B]E
    [22] -1 0   0x0000ffa0 - 0x0000ffbf (0x20) IX[B]E
    [23] -1 0   0x00002e00 - 0x00002eff (0x100) IX[B]E
    [24] -1 0   0x00002d00 - 0x00002dff (0x100) IX[B]E
    [25] -1 0   0x0000dc00 - 0x0000dcff (0x100) IX[B]E
    [26] -1 0   0x0000ec00 - 0x0000ec7f (0x80) IX[B](B)
(II) PCI Memory resource overlap reduced 0xfdfc0000 from 0xfdffffff to 0xfdfdffff
(II) PCI Memory resource overlap reduced 0xfdfe0000 from 0xfdffffff to 0xfdfeffff
(II) PCI Memory resource overlap reduced 0xfcffa000 from 0xfcffbfff to 0xfcffa3ff
(II) PCI I/O resource overlap reduced 0x0000c800 from 0x0000c8ff to 0x0000c87f
(II) PCI Memory resource overlap reduced 0xfcffa800 from 0xfcffafff to 0xfcffabff
(II) PCI Memory resource overlap reduced 0xfcff8000 from 0xfcffffff to 0xfcff8fff
(II) PCI I/O resource overlap reduced 0x0000d000 from 0x0000d0ff to 0x0000d07f
(II) PCI I/O resource overlap reduced 0x0000d400 from 0x0000d4ff to 0x0000d47f
(II) Active PCI resource ranges after removing overlaps:
    [0] -1  0   0xfdfb0000 - 0xfdfbffff (0x10000) MX[B]E
    [1] -1  0   0xfdfc0000 - 0xfdfdffff (0x20000) MX[B]E
    [2] -1  0   0xfdfe0000 - 0xfdfeffff (0x10000) MX[B]E
    [3] -1  0   0xfdff0000 - 0xfdffffff (0x10000) MX[B]E
    [4] -1  0   0xfcff6c00 - 0xfcff6fff (0x400) MX[B]E
    [5] -1  0   0xfcffa000 - 0xfcffa3ff (0x400) MX[B]E
    [6] -1  0   0xfcff7000 - 0xfcff7fff (0x1000) MX[B]E
    [7] -1  0   0xfcffa400 - 0xfcffa7ff (0x400) MX[B]E
    [8] -1  0   0xfcffa800 - 0xfcffabff (0x400) MX[B]E
    [9] -1  0   0xfcff8000 - 0xfcff8fff (0x1000) MX[B]E
    [10] -1 0   0xfcff9000 - 0xfcff9fff (0x1000) MX[B]E
    [11] -1 0   0xfcffac00 - 0xfcffafff (0x400) MX[B]E
    [12] -1 0   0xfcffb000 - 0xfcffbfff (0x1000) MX[B]E
    [13] -1 0   0xfdee0000 - 0xfdefffff (0x20000) MX[B](B)
    [14] -1 0   0xfd000000 - 0xfd7fffff (0x800000) MX[B](B)
    [15] -1 0   0x0000c800 - 0x0000c87f (0x80) IX[B]E
    [16] -1 0   0x0000c880 - 0x0000c8ff (0x80) IX[B]E
    [17] -1 0   0x0000cc00 - 0x0000ccff (0x100) IX[B]E
    [18] -1 0   0x0000d000 - 0x0000d07f (0x80) IX[B]E
    [19] -1 0   0x0000d080 - 0x0000d0ff (0x80) IX[B]E
    [20] -1 0   0x0000d400 - 0x0000d47f (0x80) IX[B]E
    [21] -1 0   0x0000d480 - 0x0000d4ff (0x80) IX[B]E
    [22] -1 0   0x0000ffa0 - 0x0000ffbf (0x20) IX[B]E
    [23] -1 0   0x00002e00 - 0x00002eff (0x100) IX[B]E
    [24] -1 0   0x00002d00 - 0x00002dff (0x100) IX[B]E
    [25] -1 0   0x0000dc00 - 0x0000dcff (0x100) IX[B]E
    [26] -1 0   0x0000ec00 - 0x0000ec7f (0x80) IX[B](B)
(II) OS-reported resource ranges after removing overlaps with PCI:
    [0] -1  0   0xffe00000 - 0xffffffff (0x200000) MX[B](B)
    [1] -1  0   0x00100000 - 0x3fffffff (0x3ff00000) MX[B]E(B)
    [2] -1  0   0x000f0000 - 0x000fffff (0x10000) MX[B]
    [3] -1  0   0x000c0000 - 0x000effff (0x30000) MX[B]
    [4] -1  0   0x00000000 - 0x0009ffff (0xa0000) MX[B]
    [5] -1  0   0x0000ffff - 0x0000ffff (0x1) IX[B]
    [6] -1  0   0x00000000 - 0x000000ff (0x100) IX[B]
(II) All system resource ranges:
    [0] -1  0   0xffe00000 - 0xffffffff (0x200000) MX[B](B)
    [1] -1  0   0x00100000 - 0x3fffffff (0x3ff00000) MX[B]E(B)
    [2] -1  0   0x000f0000 - 0x000fffff (0x10000) MX[B]
    [3] -1  0   0x000c0000 - 0x000effff (0x30000) MX[B]
    [4] -1  0   0x00000000 - 0x0009ffff (0xa0000) MX[B]
    [5] -1  0   0xfdfb0000 - 0xfdfbffff (0x10000) MX[B]E
    [6] -1  0   0xfdfc0000 - 0xfdfdffff (0x20000) MX[B]E
    [7] -1  0   0xfdfe0000 - 0xfdfeffff (0x10000) MX[B]E
    [8] -1  0   0xfdff0000 - 0xfdffffff (0x10000) MX[B]E
    [9] -1  0   0xfcff6c00 - 0xfcff6fff (0x400) MX[B]E
    [10] -1 0   0xfcffa000 - 0xfcffa3ff (0x400) MX[B]E
    [11] -1 0   0xfcff7000 - 0xfcff7fff (0x1000) MX[B]E
    [12] -1 0   0xfcffa400 - 0xfcffa7ff (0x400) MX[B]E
    [13] -1 0   0xfcffa800 - 0xfcffabff (0x400) MX[B]E
    [14] -1 0   0xfcff8000 - 0xfcff8fff (0x1000) MX[B]E
    [15] -1 0   0xfcff9000 - 0xfcff9fff (0x1000) MX[B]E
    [16] -1 0   0xfcffac00 - 0xfcffafff (0x400) MX[B]E
    [17] -1 0   0xfcffb000 - 0xfcffbfff (0x1000) MX[B]E
    [18] -1 0   0xfdee0000 - 0xfdefffff (0x20000) MX[B](B)
    [19] -1 0   0xfd000000 - 0xfd7fffff (0x800000) MX[B](B)
    [20] -1 0   0x0000ffff - 0x0000ffff (0x1) IX[B]
    [21] -1 0   0x00000000 - 0x000000ff (0x100) IX[B]
    [22] -1 0   0x0000c800 - 0x0000c87f (0x80) IX[B]E
    [23] -1 0   0x0000c880 - 0x0000c8ff (0x80) IX[B]E
    [24] -1 0   0x0000cc00 - 0x0000ccff (0x100) IX[B]E
    [25] -1 0   0x0000d000 - 0x0000d07f (0x80) IX[B]E
    [26] -1 0   0x0000d080 - 0x0000d0ff (0x80) IX[B]E
    [27] -1 0   0x0000d400 - 0x0000d47f (0x80) IX[B]E
    [28] -1 0   0x0000d480 - 0x0000d4ff (0x80) IX[B]E
    [29] -1 0   0x0000ffa0 - 0x0000ffbf (0x20) IX[B]E
    [30] -1 0   0x00002e00 - 0x00002eff (0x100) IX[B]E
    [31] -1 0   0x00002d00 - 0x00002dff (0x100) IX[B]E
    [32] -1 0   0x0000dc00 - 0x0000dcff (0x100) IX[B]E
    [33] -1 0   0x0000ec00 - 0x0000ec7f (0x80) IX[B](B)
(II) LoadModule: "IA"
(II) Loading /usr/X11/lib/modules/extensions/libIA.so
(II) Module IANAME: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 6.8.0, module version = 1.0.0
    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 0.2
(II) Loading extension SolarisIA
(II) LoadModule: "Xst"
(II) Loading /usr/X11/lib/modules/extensions/libXst.so
(II) Module Xst: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 6.8.0, module version = 1.0.0
    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 0.2
(II) Loading extension ST
(II) LoadModule: "dbe"
(II) Loading /usr/X11/lib/modules/extensions/libdbe.so
(II) Module dbe: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 6.9.0, module version = 1.0.0
    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 0.2
(II) Loading extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
(II) LoadModule: "extmod"
(II) Loading /usr/X11/lib/modules/extensions/libextmod.so
(II) Module extmod: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 6.9.0, module version = 1.0.0
    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 0.2
(II) Loading extension SHAPE
(II) Loading extension MIT-SUNDRY-NONSTANDARD
(II) Loading extension BIG-REQUESTS
(II) Loading extension SYNC
(II) Loading extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
(II) Loading extension XC-MISC
(II) Loading extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
(II) Loading extension XFree86-Misc
(II) Loading extension XFree86-DGA
(II) Loading extension DPMS
(II) Loading extension TOG-CUP
(II) Loading extension Extended-Visual-Information
(II) Loading extension XVideo
(II) Loading extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
(II) Loading extension X-Resource
(II) Loading extension XEVIE
(II) LoadModule: "record"
(II) Loading /usr/X11/lib/modules/extensions/librecord.so
(II) Module record: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 6.8.0, module version = 1.13.0
    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 0.2
(II) Loading extension RECORD
(II) LoadModule: "xtrap"
(II) Loading /usr/X11/lib/modules/extensions/libxtrap.so
(II) Module xtrap: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 6.8.0, module version = 1.0.0
    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 0.2
(II) Loading extension DEC-XTRAP
(II) LoadModule: "glx"
(II) Loading /usr/X11/lib/modules/extensions/libglx.so
(II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 6.9.0, module version = 1.0.0
    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 0.2
(II) Loading sub module "GLcore"
(II) LoadModule: "GLcore"
(II) Loading /usr/X11/lib/modules/extensions/libGLcore.so
(II) Module GLcore: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 6.9.0, module version = 1.0.0
    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 0.2
(II) Loading extension GLX
(II) LoadModule: "bitstream"
(II) Loading /usr/X11/lib/modules/fonts/libbitstream.so
(II) Module bitstream: vendor="Sun Microsystems, Inc."
    compiled for 6.8.0, module version = 1.0.0
    Module class: X.Org Font Renderer
    ABI class: X.Org Font Renderer, version 0.4
(II) Loading font Bitstream
(II) LoadModule: "type1"
(II) Loading /usr/X11/lib/modules/fonts/libtype1.so
(II) Module type1: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 6.8.2, module version = 1.0.2
    Module class: X.Org Font Renderer
    ABI class: X.Org Font Renderer, version 0.4
(II) Loading font Type1
(II) Loading font CID
(II) LoadModule: "ast"
(II) Loading /usr/X11/lib/modules/drivers/ast_drv.so
(II) Module ast: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 6.9.0, module version = 0.80.0
    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 0.8
(II) LoadModule: "mouse"
(II) Loading /usr/X11/lib/modules/input/mouse_drv.so
(II) Module mouse: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 6.9.0, module version = 1.0.3
    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 0.5
(II) AST: Driver for ASPEED Graphics Chipsets: AST2000
(II) Primary Device is: PCI 01:05:0
(--) Chipset AST2000 found
(II) resource ranges after xf86ClaimFixedResources() call:
    [0] -1  0   0xffe00000 - 0xffffffff (0x200000) MX[B](B)
    [1] -1  0   0x00100000 - 0x3fffffff (0x3ff00000) MX[B]E(B)
    [2] -1  0   0x000f0000 - 0x000fffff (0x10000) MX[B]
    [3] -1  0   0x000c0000 - 0x000effff (0x30000) MX[B]

..................................

    [27] -1 0   0x0000d400 - 0x0000d47f (0x80) IX[B]E
    [28] -1 0   0x0000d480 - 0x0000d4ff (0x80) IX[B]E
    [29] -1 0   0x0000ffa0 - 0x0000ffbf (0x20) IX[B]E
    [30] -1 0   0x00002e00 - 0x00002eff (0x100) IX[B]E
    [31] -1 0   0x00002d00 - 0x00002dff (0x100) IX[B]E
    [32] -1 0   0x0000dc00 - 0x0000dcff (0x100) IX[B]E
    [33] -1 0   0x0000ec00 - 0x0000ec7f (0x80) IX[B](B)
(II) resource ranges after probing:
    [0] -1  0   0xffe00000 - 0xffffffff (0x200000) MX[B](B)
    [1] -1  0   0x00100000 - 0x3fffffff (0x3ff00000) MX[B]E(B)
    [2] -1  0   0x000f0000 - 0x000fffff (0x10000) MX[B]
    [3] -1  0   0x000c0000 - 0x000effff (0x30000) MX[B]
    [4] -1  0   0x00000000 - 0x0009ffff (0xa0000) MX[B]

.................................

    [34] -1 0   0x00002d00 - 0x00002dff (0x100) IX[B]E
    [35] -1 0   0x0000dc00 - 0x0000dcff (0x100) IX[B]E
    [36] -1 0   0x0000ec00 - 0x0000ec7f (0x80) IX[B](B)
    [37] 0  0   0x000003b0 - 0x000003bb (0xc) IS[B]
    [38] 0  0   0x000003c0 - 0x000003df (0x20) IS[B]
(II) Setting vga for screen 0.
(II) Loading sub module "vgahw"
(II) LoadModule: "vgahw"
(II) Loading /usr/X11/lib/modules/libvgahw.so
(II) Module vgahw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 6.9.0, module version = 0.1.0
    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 0.8
(II) Loading sub module "fb"
(II) LoadModule: "fb"
(II) Loading /usr/X11/lib/modules/libfb.so
(II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 6.9.0, module version = 1.0.0
    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.2
(++) AST(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
(==) AST(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
(==) AST(0): RGB weight 888
(==) AST(0): Default visual is TrueColor
(--) AST(0): Chipset: "AST2000"
(II) AST(0): Linear framebuffer at 0xFD000000
(II) AST(0): IO registers at addr 0xFDEE0000
(II) Loading sub module "vbe"
(II) LoadModule: "vbe"
(II) Loading /usr/X11/lib/modules/libvbe.so
(II) Module vbe: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 6.9.0, module version = 1.1.0
    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 0.8
(II) Loading sub module "int10"
(II) LoadModule: "int10"
(II) Loading /usr/X11/lib/modules/libint10.so
(II) Module int10: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 6.9.0, module version = 1.0.0
    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 0.8
(II) AST(0): initializing int10
(II) AST(0): Primary V_BIOS segment is: 0xc000
(II) AST(0): VESA BIOS detected
(II) AST(0): VESA VBE Version 3.0
(II) AST(0): VESA VBE Total Mem: 8192 kB
(II) AST(0): VESA VBE OEM: ASPEED
(II) AST(0): VESA VBE OEM Software Rev: 1.0
(II) AST(0): VESA VBE OEM Vendor: ASPEED Technology, Inc.
(II) AST(0): VESA VBE OEM Product: AST GPU
(II) AST(0): VESA VBE OEM Product Rev: 0.81.01 
(II) Loading sub module "ddc"
(II) LoadModule: "ddc"
(II) Loading /usr/X11/lib/modules/libddc.so
(II) Module ddc: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 6.9.0, module version = 1.0.0
    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 0.8
(II) AST(0): VESA VBE DDC supported
(II) AST(0): VESA VBE DDC Level none
(II) AST(0): VESA VBE DDC transfer in appr. 1 sec.
(II) AST(0): VESA VBE DDC read failed
(II) AST(0): Monitor0: Using default hsync range of 28.00-33.00 kHz
(II) AST(0): Monitor0: Using default vrefresh range of 43.00-72.00 Hz
(II) AST(0): Clock range:   9.50 to 165.00 MHz
(II) AST(0): Not using mode "1600x900@75" (no mode of this name)
(II) AST(0): Not using mode "1600x900@75" (no mode of this name)
(II) AST(0): Not using default mode "640x350" (no mode of this name)
(II) AST(0): Not using default mode "320x175" (bad mode clock/interlace/doublescan)
(II) AST(0): Not using default mode "640x400" (no mode of this name)
(II) AST(0): Not using default mode "320x200" (bad mode clock/interlace/doublescan)
(II) AST(0): Not using default mode "720x400" (no mode of this name)
(II) AST(0): Not using default mode "360x200" (bad mode clock/interlace/doublescan)
(II) AST(0): Not using default mode "320x240" (bad mode clock/interlace/doublescan)

....................................................

(II) AST(0): Not using default mode "1920x1080" (width requires unsupported line pitch)
(II) AST(0): Not using default mode "960x540" (bad mode clock/interlace/doublescan)
(II) AST(0): Not using default mode "1920x1200" (insufficient memory for mode)
(II) AST(0): Not using default mode "960x600" (bad mode clock/interlace/doublescan)
(II) AST(0): Not using default mode "1920x1200" (insufficient memory for mode)
(II) AST(0): Not using default mode "960x600" (bad mode clock/interlace/doublescan)
(II) AST(0): Not using mode "1600x900@75" (no mode of this name)
(--) AST(0): Virtual size is 640x480 (pitch 640)
(**) AST(0):  Default mode "640x480": 25.2 MHz, 31.5 kHz, 60.0 Hz
(II) AST(0): Modeline "640x480"   25.20  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync
(==) AST(0): DPI set to (75, 75)
(II) Loading sub module "xaa"
(II) LoadModule: "xaa"
(II) Loading /usr/X11/lib/modules/libxaa.so
(II) Module xaa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 6.9.0, module version = 1.2.0
    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 0.8
(II) AST(0): No ENG Capability options found
(II) AST(0): No DBG Seleclt options found
(II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
(II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
(II) Loading /usr/X11/lib/modules/libramdac.so
(II) Module ramdac: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 6.8.2, module version = 0.1.0
    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 0.7
(II) AST(0): No HWC_NUM options found
(--) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
(II) do I need RAC?  No, I don't.
(II) resource ranges after preInit:
    [0] 0   0   0xfdee0000 - 0xfdefffff (0x20000) MX[B]
    [1] 0   0   0xfd000000 - 0xfd7fffff (0x800000) MX[B]
    [2] -1  0   0xffe00000 - 0xffffffff (0x200000) MX[B](B)
    [3] -1  0   0x00100000 - 0x3fffffff (0x3ff00000) MX[B]E(B)

....................................

    [39] -1 0   0x0000ec00 - 0x0000ec7f (0x80) IX[B](B)
    [40] 0  0   0x000003b0 - 0x000003bb (0xc) IS[B](OprU)
    [41] 0  0   0x000003c0 - 0x000003df (0x20) IS[B](OprU)
(II) AST(0): vgaHWGetIOBase: hwp->IOBase is 0x03d0, hwp->PIOOffset is 0xe880
(II) AST(0): Allocate CMDQ size is 1024 kbyte 
(II) AST(0): Using XFree86 Acceleration Architecture (XAA)
    Screen to screen bit blits
    Solid filled rectangles
    8x8 mono pattern filled rectangles
    8x8 color pattern filled rectangles
    Solid Lines
    Dashed Lines
    Offscreen Pixmaps
    Setting up tile and stipple cache:
        20 128x128 slots
        5 256x256 slots
        32 8x8 color pattern slots
(==) AST(0): Backing store disabled
(==) AST(0): Silken mouse disabled
(==) RandR enabled
(II) Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
(II) Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
(II) Initializing built-in extension XTEST
(II) Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
(II) Initializing built-in extension LBX
(II) Initializing built-in extension XC-APPGROUP
(II) Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
(II) Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
(II) Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
(II) Initializing built-in extension XFree86-Bigfont
(II) Initializing built-in extension RENDER
(II) Initializing built-in extension RANDR
(II) Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
(II) Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
(II) Initializing built-in extension XEVIE
(**) Option "Protocol" "auto"
(II) Mouse0: Setting Device option to "/dev/mouse"
(**) Mouse0: Protocol: VUID
(**) Option "CorePointer"
(**) Mouse0: Core Pointer
(**) Option "Device" "/dev/mouse"
(II) Mouse0: Setting Buttons option to "3"
(==) Mouse0: Emulate3Buttons, Emulate3Timeout: 50
(**) Option "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
(**) Mouse0: ZAxisMapping: buttons 4, 5, 6 and 7
(**) Mouse0: Buttons: 11
(WW) *** WARNING the legacy keyboard driver "keyboard" is deprecated
(WW) *** and will be removed in the next release of the Xorg server.
(WW) *** Please consider using the the new "kbd" driver for "Keyboard0".
(II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Mouse0" (type: MOUSE)
(II) Keyboard0: Opened device "/dev/kbd"
(--) Keyboard0: Keyboard type: USB (6)
(--) Keyboard0: Keyboard layout: 33
(--) XKB: model: "sun_type6_usb"
(--) XKB: layout: "us"
```

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong. Maybe the X server doesn't like your modeline for some reason. Post the relevant parts of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` (the whole thing if you're unsure what's relevant).

Comment: I am sorry, I thought that those files were not touched since a few hours before my last attempt, but it turned out that the clock was wrong. I will post the log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is my video card. I switched from Xorg to Xsun and it seems no matter what I choose using Xsun, I will always get one of 1600x1200, 1280x1024, 1024x768, 800x600 or 640x480. So I switched back to Xorg and I will settle with the choices that work.